# find outputs an extra empty line

Tags: linux, bash, find

Im using the find command to find common files between two directories:

```
find  "$SOURCE" "$TARGET" -printf "$TARGET%P\n" | sort | uniq -d
```

problem is it always outputs an empty line on the top. Due to that when I try to delete the common files from the source like this:

```
find  "$SOURCE" "$TARGET" -printf "$TARGET%P\n" | sort | uniq -d | xargs rm
```

I get error:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/target/directory/path’: Is a directory
```

How top get rid of the extra line

Comment: Add `! -type d` before the `-printf` to suppress printing the directory.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using `xargs rm` here since that results in, essentailly, parsing the output of `ls`, which is [a classic antipattern](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Instead, you could do something like:

```
for tgt in "$TARGET"/*; do
    if [[ -e "$SOURCE/${tgt##*/}" ]]; then
        rm "$tgt"
    fi
done
```

of course, that won't recurse, so if you wanted that you can use `find` like so:

```
find "$TARGET" -type f -exec bash -c 'if [ -e "${1//$TARGET/$SOURCE}" ]; then rm "$1"; fi' "" {} \;
```

or apparently there's a tool called [`fdupes`](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes) that sounds like it might do the job for you

Comment: just wondering, if I have lots of files in my target will using find be faster?

Comment: You'd have to profile to be sure, but my gut here is that the for loop would be faster since the `find` will have to spawn a shell to do the existence test for each file

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty -> add `tail -n +1` leading to `find  "$SOURCE" "$TARGET" -printf "$TARGET%P\n" | tail -n +1 | sort | uniq -d | xargs rm`

Comment: You cold also avoid the top folder leading to the empty line `find  "$SOURCE" -mindepth 1 "$TARGET" -printf "$TARGET%P\n" | sort | uniq -d | xargs rm`

Answer (score 1):

A much quicker way to check for differences between directories:

```
diff -qr "$source" "$target"
```

Another solution is to ask `find` specifically for files only by using `-type f`.

You can also suppress the printing of the starting points by using `-mindepth 1`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SOURCE=folder1/ ;
TARGET=folder2/ ;
find  "$SOURCE" "$TARGET" -type f -printf "$TARGET%P\n" | sort | uniq -d | xargs rm
```

Do not forget to append `/` in source and target path.